# IE: 'Open in new tab' doesn't affect state of link (i.e. a:visited)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Whenever I click with IE9 on a link on my website, the color of the visited link changes according to the a:visited style in my stylesheet. On the other hand, when I click on the same link with the right mouse button and choose "Open in new tab", the link opens in a new tab but doesn't change the color of the link. How could I achieve that the a:visited style would be used in the 'new tab' case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around, I only found Reddit changing the link color when you open pages this way. They do this by applying a 'click' class to the link when the user uses the right mouse button. On Reddit, this doesn't persist in IE if you refresh the page (like it does with links opened in another way).

In order to get the link color to persist, you would need to store the user information somewhere and re-apply that class as necessary. This is probably overkill and unnecessary for a browser bug.

Comment: I have tried it on Google in IE9 and the links don't change to the visited state either. IE9 version is 9.0.8112.16421.

Comment: Apologies, I was opening the new tabs with a different method than you described above. This isn't something you will be able to fix with just CSS. You would have to somehow keep track of the links the user went to and fake in the visited state. Reddit adds a 'clicked' class to a link if the user right or left clicks it, but it then has to store that somewhere so that it is persistant.